# Реализовать Быструю сортировку (Quicksort) для строк

Tags: c#, сортировка

Дан какой-то массив, например, из 50-ти строк. Как его отсортировать методом "Быстрой сортировки" по длине строки?

Comment: @Air, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Quicksort
{
    class Program
    {
        static string[] Quicksort(string[] s)
        {
            if (s.Length < 2) { return s; }
            int p = s[0].Length;
            return Quicksort(s.Where(x => x.Length < p).ToArray())
                .Concat(s.Where(x => x.Length == p))
                .Concat(Quicksort(s.Where(x => x.Length > p).ToArray()))
                .ToArray();
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            foreach (string s in Quicksort(Console.ReadLine().Split().ToArray()))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StringArrQuickSort
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] unsorted = {
            "У меня хорошее настроение.",
            "Хоар молодец!",
            "Привет мир!",
            "Еслиб Хоар не знал русский язык, выдумал бы он этот алгоритм?" };

        string[] sorted = stringQuickSort(unsorted);

        sorted.ToList().ForEach(x=> Console.WriteLine(x));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    static string[] stringQuickSort(string[] unsA)
    {
        int[] indA = unsA.Select(x => x.Length).ToArray();
        int i = 0;
        Dictionary<int, int> sAI = indA.ToDictionary(x => x, x => i++);

        quickSort(indA, 0, indA.Length-1);

        return indA.Select(x => unsA[sAI[x]]).ToArray<string>();
    }

    /*http://cybern.ru/qsort-csharp.html*/
    static void quickSort(int[] a, int l, int r)
    {
        int temp;
        int x = a[l + (r - l) / 2];
        //запись эквивалентна (l+r)/2, 
        //но не вызввает переполнения на больших данных
        int i = l;
        int j = r;
        //код в while обычно выносят в процедуру particle
        while (i <= j)
        {
            while (a[i] < x) i++;
            while (a[j] > x) j--;
            if (i <= j)
            {
                temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        if (i < r)
            quickSort(a, i, r);

        if (l < j)
            quickSort(a, l, j);
    }
}
}
```