# Как красиво реализовать сортировку

Tags: c#, .net, сортировка, .net-4.8

Есть такой список элементов

```
["Петя", "Вова", "Аня", "Катя", "Саня", "Олег"]
```

Условие сортировки:

```
Аня должна быть первой
Петя перед Катей
Катя перед Вовой
Олег последним
```

Вывод:

```
["Аня", "Петя", "Катя", "Вова", "Саня", "Олег"]
```

Как сортировать лучше всего?

Использую C# Fm 4.7.2 (так что новинки языка не подойдут :D )

Но ответ можно и на любом языке, главное логика =)

Пока мысли о пузырьковым методе, грубо сравнивая текста

Comment: Не разбираюсь в C#, но быть может это то что вам нужно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/410919/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%91%d1%8b%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d1%83-quicksort-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поскольку задан частичный порядок, вам подойдёт [топологическая сортировка](https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/499138/). [Или здесь](https://e-maxx.ru/algo/topological_sort).

Ваши условия - дуги направленного графа, первое и последнее условия задают по 5 дуг.